# ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Can't create render surface

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, game-engine, cocos2d-x

Using cocos2d-x-2.0.4 framework using opengles2.0, the app build based android sdk 2.2 and run on device Galaxy Nexus(Android version 4.1.2), after loading several images(png and jpg), generates this error:

```
:0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem: Error 1 returned
:0: ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Can't create render surface.
```

What's the problem? hope somebody can shed light upon this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading compressed textures, probably the device went out of memory, besides it is more efficient and you will not saturate the bus. Is there any more information at LogCat?

Probably if you invert the other, first create render surface and then textures, one of your textures will fail.